# Two way communication between two micro services (spring boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, resttemplate

I have two micro services *M1* and *M2*, I need to send request to *M2* from *M1*, and I need to wait for the response from *M2*, because the code works based on the response from *M2*
How to implement this in `spring boot`?

Comment: You need to include what you have tried uptil now. Understand how a question is asked on Stackoverflow. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Its is for migration to micro services ,we havent started yet .

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do it. I will suggest you to implement a `producer/consumer` pattern between *M1* and *M2* with a messaging tool such as `Active MQ`, `Rabbit MQ` or `Kafka`.

1. *M1* produce a message to a queue *Q1*
2. *M2* process the message from *Q1*
3. *M2* returns a response to *Q2*
4. *M1* consume the message from *Q2*

Take a look [here](https://www.theserverside.com/answer/Synchronous-vs-asynchronous-microservices-communication-patterns).

Comment: First of all ,thank you for responding sir
In asynchronous messaging system response is independent of time right ? So i need response when ever i send request ,because based on the response only i can proceed in m1

Comment: There is no issue about that. If you don't have a message in the queue, anything won't be processed.

Comment: I would second this answer, a pub / sub architecture would be able to hold the output more safely than two services calling each other back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

Create a REST API in your M1 micro service through a controller and then call it from M2 using some API client library.

Comment: Can you elaborate in terms of spring framework?

Comment: Here you will need to use a rest client such as `RestTemplate` or  `WebClient` to call M1 service from inside M2

Answer (score 1):

You create REST API in M2 that will consume or respond to your input from M1

for instance you may have following endpoint in your @RestController annotated class in M2:

```
@GetMapping("/consumer")
public ResponseEntity<YourResponseDTO> produceResponse(){
    YourResponseDTO result = resultOfYourBusinessLogic();
return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
```

Then in your M1 service the easiest in my opinion is to use RestTemplate to call M2
Here is an example:

```
RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
YourResponseDTO result = rt.getForObject("http://urlOfYourM2/consumer", YourResponseDTO.class);
```

Please note that this is just an example of call for GET request that produces "YourReponseDTO" Object.
You gave very less details about the actual needs of the message exchange and thus the RestTemplate may be used in different ways (different types of request PUT/POST/etc...) you can customize it according needs with error handlers, connection timeout settings etc.

Downside of this approach is that you need to share between M1 and M2 a DTO model to properly map the response objects.
But anyways RestTemplate is a client implementation you can use to communicate synchronously between microservices

Comment: Thank you for the response sir ,Is there any other way for this ? I mean other than rest template ?

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of ways. RestTemplate is just one of them. I suggested it because it is easy in use and is included in Spring as you requested. Could you be more specific what you need? Which of your expectation RestTemplate don't meet?

Comment: We are working on bank application ,so is it recommended for that purpose?

Comment: WebClient library is recommended when developing APIs using Webflux, and RestTemplate library when developing with older spring boot

Answer (score 0):

You can use synchronous communication with the declarative Rest client "Spring Cloud OpenFeign" as bellow :

[Spring Cloud - Synchronous Communication with Feign](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_cloud/spring_cloud_synchronous_communication_with_feign.htm)

Answer (score 0):

in most of case its always recommended to use asynchronous communication between services to maintain them decouple. if you want use asynchronous communication for your case you need to implement bio-directional event channel as @Harry Coder. how ever its require to implement patterns such as SAGA,CAP Theory, circuit breaker to bring reliability to such implementation specially your case since you waiting for immediate response.

if immediate response is critical you can use synchronous communication such as API call or gRPC. if you need performant and fast communication gRPC worth to implement for those services. it is good to use libraries like [Mass Transit](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/transports/grpc.html) for less coupling in your implementation.

**Update**
if you insist using synchronous communication and the response is critically important i recommend choosing gRPC. it let you provide two way communication.

you can setup a service as client or server or both server/Client which the third implementation stablish two-way communication between M1 and M2.

in gRPC you need to write protocol called protobuffer which makes this communication robust.
it is worth to consider it over rest in some cases.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for responding sir,we are working on bank application ,is it recommended to use rest template? To consume that external api ?

Comment: there is no absolute right way. it depends. maybe some part of your system wiring asynchronously and some synchronously. generally client-app call services with api  call (rest if you want) since response is require and communication between services handled by events. that is why you must be more specific about the subject you want to select communication. are we talking about getting account balance service, or transferring service for example. anyway if you insist two way communication in sensitive area i recommend gRPC which let you implement two way communication. i edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you sir, M1 calls m2 and m2 gives some data  (M2 never calls m1) ,so grpc can be used right?

Comment: in that case M2 is Server grpc and M1 client grpc . additionally choose this approach if 1-need fast response 2-secure response 3-robust communication (since you write protocol for communication) because the implementation is more time consuming than rest. read this article https://medium.com/@sankar.p/how-grpc-convinced-me-to-chose-it-over-rest-30408bf42794

Comment: Thank you sir,can we call Soap (external ) webservice using gRPC?

Comment: i think thats a miss understanding ... raed https://dev.to/andreidascalu/soap-vs-rest-vs-grpc-vs-graphql-1ib6.  it is requires for both parties to have grpc implementation(server/client) to communicate. they share the protobuffer protocol with each other.  before there were rpc for xml and rpc for json. but google introduce g as generic rpc.

Comment: Ok ,i got it know ,thank you so much for responding sir